# Jquery autocomplete with label and links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jquery autocomplete working perfect for label and it's value.

```
$( "#search_name" ).autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/fetch_search_suggestion",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            keyword: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label
                }
            }));
        }
    })
}
});
```

**PHP**

```
while($search = $result->fetch()){
        $link = '';
        $link .= $search['cus_firstname'].' '.$search['cus_lastname'];
        array_push($searchArray, array('label'=> $link, 'value' => $keyword));
    }
array_push($searchArray, array('label'=>"Not Here? Click to add new", 'value' =>"http://www.google.com"));
```

If customer is not there, on click add new it should go to the `google.com`. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

I tried with adding:

```
 select : function(event, ui) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
       return {
         window.location  = (ui.item.value);
         return false;
        }
       }));
 }
```

But, I am getting error.